# Rails 5: ActiveRecord not creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a modified version of Michael Hartl's Learn Rails Tutorial. I'm on chapter 6, modeling users. For some reason, my users aren't creating correctly on ActiveRecord and aren't saving at all.

I placed these users in my `seeds.rb` file

```
user_1 = User.create(id: 1, name: 'Han Solo', email: 'han@example.com')
user_2 = User.create(id: 2, name: 'Luke Skywalker', email: 'luke@example.com')
```

Then I run `rails db:seed`, but if I go to my `rails console`, it appears like no users have been created:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 24358
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.2.2 :001 > User.delete_all
  SQL (1.1ms)  DELETE FROM "users"
 => 0 
2.2.2 :002 >
```

`user.rb` User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    #Ensure Email Uniqueness by Downcasing the Email Attribute
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase }
    #validates name, presence, and length
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
    #Validate presence, length, format, and uniqueness (ignoring case)
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 250}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    #Adds ability to save securely hashed password_digest attribute to database
    #Adds a pair of virtual attributes (password and password_confirmation)
    #including presence validations upon object creation and a validation
    #requiring that they match
    #adds authenticate method that returns the user when the password is correct (and false otherwise)
    has_secure_password
    PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
        (?=.{8,})          # Must contain 8 or more characters
        (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
        (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
        (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
        (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
    /x
    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8}, format: {with: PASSWORD_FORMAT}

end

schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161020211218) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

end
```

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Do you already have that user in your database? It appears when you check `valid?` it is returning false because the email address is already used.

Comment: Please the IANA sandbox domain `@example.com` instead of real gmail addresses for examples. It saves whoever owns the address from getting harvested by spambots.

Comment: after calling `user.valid?` call `user.errors.full_messages` to see what's preventing the same.

Comment: I think you may be confused by the `user.valid?` line. `=> false ` is the return value of the `.valid?` method call - not the database query.

Comment: Hey check out my code I just updated it showing when I run rails db:seed and then rails console and User.delete_all to delete the users I just created, it seems like they're not there.

Comment: `User.create!( id: 1, name: 'Han Solo', email: 'han@example.com' )` You don't  want to wrap the attributes in a array. The `{}` is optional since ruby treats the arguments as a hash anyways. Use `create!` in your seeds file as it will raise an exception and tell you if something is wrong.

Comment: @max that didnt' fix it

Comment: Did you try changing it to `create!`? Also don't pass the id. The database assigns it automatically.

Comment: hey @max I figured it out and posted my answer thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out.

1. I took out id from the seeds.rb. When I took out the id attribute, it started throwing me the error of the user not having a valid password. I then added a password and password confirmation to conform to password standards set in my user model.
2. Updated my model and added a password confirmation.

Here's my updated `user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    #Ensure Email Uniqueness by Downcasing the Email Attribute
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase }
    #validates name, presence, and length
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
    #Validate presence, length, format, and uniqueness (ignoring case)
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 250}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    #Adds ability to save securely hashed password_digest attribute to database
    #Adds a pair of virtual attributes (password and password_confirmation)
    #including presence validations upon object creation and a validation
    #requiring that they match
    #adds authenticate method that returns the user when the password is correct (and false otherwise)
    has_secure_password
    PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
        (?=.{8,})          # Must contain 8 or more characters
        (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
        (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
        (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
        (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
    /x
    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8}, format: {with: PASSWORD_FORMAT}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And `seeds.rb`

```
user_1 = User.create!(name: 'Han Solo', email: 'han@example.com', password: 'Password123!', password_confirmation: 'Password123!')
user_2 = User.create!(name: 'Luke Skywalker', email: 'luke@example.com', password: 'Password123!', password_confirmation: 'Password123!')
```

I tested that the user is being created properly by opening up the rails console, running `User.delete_all` , and seeing them wiped off the SQL record.

Comment: You never assign IDs to records - the database auto-increments the id column and it returns the id as part of the INSERT sql query.

Comment: Thanks again for reaffirming that! I'll keep that in mind.